# how to add values to a method with return type list

Tags: c#

The problem which i am facing is in adding values to the method with return type list. I am sending values from another class. when the i want to enter to values from the array into the method of the other class i gives me the paring error.

here is the code which i am using: (class from where i will send data)

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   public static double GetDistance()
    {
        string[] rep = new string[] { "51.48797159999999", "-0.16511850000006234", "51.492172", "-0.16144499999995787"};
        List<getLatLong> lst = new List<getLatLong>();      

        for (int i = 0; i < rep.Length; i++)
        {
            lst.Add(new getLatLong { Lat = rep[i], Lng= rep[i + 1] });  //i am getting the error over here
            i++;
        }
     }
}
```

class getLatLong is the class where i am going to send and add value to its return type list methods:

```
public class getLatLong
{
    public getLatLong()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    private List<double> lat;

    public List<double> Lat
    {
        get { return lat; }
        set { lat = value; }
    }

    private List<double> lng;

    public List<double> Lng
    {
        get { return lng; }
        set { lng = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? is rep[i + 1] out of bounds?

Comment: the erroe is in parsing it says that it can convert rep[i] to list where as rep[i] here is a string.

Comment: Why is there an `i++` at the end of the for loop as well as the third parameter for the for loop. Just use `i += 2` if this behavior is desired.

Comment: So `Lat` field in `getLatLong` is supposed to be a `List<?>`? If so, you cannot assign a string to it (and `rep[i]` is a string).

Comment: These are not strings: { 51.48797159999999, -0.16511850000006234, 51.492172, -0.16144499999995787};

Comment: because rep[i] is added directly to Lat and Lng properties which are a list, should be Lat.Add(rep[i]), Lng.Add(rep[ i + 1]) BTW convert the value to double by Convert.ToDouble(rep[i]) respectively

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Question gives the values as strings, I don't see a problem there

Comment: You have 'List<double> Lat' so you need to pass a List object whereas you are passing rep[i] which is a string not a List<double>.

Comment: @Sebi - they were edited...so now need to be parsed or converted to doubles

Comment: @EmmadKareem...can you give any example

Comment: You got an answer now. I am not sure why you have the property defined as List and not just a simple type?

Comment: I agree with Emmad Kareem - you should perhaps have a type for the lat/logitude and then a list of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code won't compile because a `String` is not a `List<double>` and the compiler doesn't know how to make that conversion. Technically all you would need to do is initialize your object like:

```
lst.Add(new getLatLong {
    Lat = new List<double>() {Double.Parse(rep[i])},
    Lng = new List<double>() {Double.Parse(rep[i + 1])}
  });
```

With that the code should compile. That said, there are a number of places where the code doesn't exactly make sense. For example, why is your coordinate class named `getLatLong` and also why does that class consist of a list of doubles rather than just two double values? You may want to consider a few of these things before just fixing the compiler errors. Either way, best of luck!

NOTE: If you have lots of GEO Coordinate type things to do you might just consider referencing a prebuilt library such as [GeoSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/).

Comment: i tried this code, the error is gone but when i compile it the lat and lng methods in the getlatlong class does not get value...it shows nullreference

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't compile because of incompatible types:

- In GetDistance() method, rep array should be of double[] type rather
  than string[] or else you need to convert the types while creating
  getLatLong objects.
- In GetDistance() method, while creating getLatLong objects, there is
  a incompatible type assignment, where Lat and Lng objects are
  initialized. Either these should be initialized to  List
  objects as shown in code below or the types for Lat and Lng in the
  getLatLong class should be changed to double instead of List.

```cs
public static double GetDistance()
{
   double[] rep = new double[] { 51.4879716, -0.16511850, 51.492172, -0.161445 };
   List<getLatLong> lst = new List<getLatLong>();

   for (int i = 0; i < rep.Length; i++)
   {
        lst.Add(new getLatLong {
            Lat = new List<double> {rep[i]}, 
            Lng = new List<double> {rep[i + 1]}
        });
        i++;
   }

}
```